# A more efficient regular expression for extracting astrological house data?

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a script to extract astrological house data from a birth chart PDF. I am wondering if there is a more efficient regular expression I could be using.

**Current pattern:**

```py
house_pattern = r'([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][a-z]+\.|[0-9]|[0-9]{2})\s+([a-z])\s+(\d+°+.\d+\'+.\d+\")'
```

**Example dataset:**

```
Houses (Plac.) Declination
Asc. j  3°23'49" 23°23'37" S
2 k  13°38'12" 16°43'48" S
3 l  25°39'11" 1°43'39" S
IC a  28°32'56" 10°57'28" N
5 b  23° 5'14" 18°32'35" N
6 c  13°27'11" 22°24'45" N
Desc. d  3°23'49" 23°23'37" N
8 e  13°38'12" 16°43'48" N
9 f  25°39'11" 1°43'39" N
MC g  28°32'56" 10°57'28" S
11 h  23° 5'14" 18°32'35" S
12 i  13°27'11" 22°24'45" S
```

**Desired (and current) results:**
The format is: House number or point, zodiac sign, degree/arcminute/arcsecond.

```
('Asc.', 'j', '3°23\'49"')
('2', 'k', '13°38\'12"')
('3', 'l', '25°39\'11"')
('IC', 'a', '28°32\'56"')
('5', 'b', '23° 5\'14"')
('6', 'c', '13°27\'11"')
('Desc.', 'd', '3°23\'49"')
('8', 'e', '13°38\'12"')
('9', 'f', '25°39\'11"')
('MC', 'g', '28°32\'56"')
('11', 'h', '23° 5\'14"')
('12', 'i', '13°27\'11"')
```

Currently, '*the house number / point*' group uses a ton of overly specific OR statements. How can I refactor to get the same results?

I tried the pattern above and tested on regex101.com. I did a bit of google searching but I'm struggling to find an answer similar enough to fit my use case. My current pattern does return the correct results but seems as though it could be way better.

Comment: What is the problem? If your regex works as per the requirements, it is fine as is. Does it slow your program? Do you really need a regex if you can just split with whitespaces and get the first three items?

Comment: True, I suppose I overthought it.

Comment: Why not just split the row on spaces and take the first 3 items?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
(\S+)\s+([a-z])\s+(\d+°\s*\d+'\d+")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[0-9]|[0-9]{2}
```

Whilst using `re` of python you might specify *range* in form of `{`atleast`,`atmost`}` so above piece might be expressed more succinctly as

```
[0-9]{1,2}
```